# <ion-slides> options not working

Tags: ionic-framework, slider, carousel

I want to show one slide for each page and a part of the next and previous slide on the same page similar to this:

[image]

The code I wrote is as follow:

```
 <ion-slides options="options" slider="data.slider" class="offer-slider">
        <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="offer in offers track by $index">
            <offer offer="offer" expandable="false" offerList="offers"></offer>
        </ion-slide-page>
    </ion-slides>
```

And in my controller the options are like this:

```
 $scope.msgOptions = {
    loop: true,
    effect: 'slide',
    speed: 500,
    pagination: 'false',
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidersPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true
};
```

But it's not working. Am I missing something? How could I achieve this design?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$scope.msgOptions` to `$scope.options`.
In your template you name your options variable "options" and not "msgOptions".So the options that you set in your controller won't be assign.